# I have embedded visuals from a power bi report, is it possible to fetch the data inside these?

Tags: javascript, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I have these visuals: [image: Visuals] that I want to fetch only the title "Førstehjelp" and the value "50" from, without the frame around etc. Is this possible with Javascript or do I have to edit the power bi report to make it look the way I want?

Comment: After fetching do you want the export or you want to change the values ?

Comment: The exports, if that means being able to only fetch the value inside the visual without the power bi styles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `visual.exportData` to export data from a report visual.

Follow the below steps:

1. Get the Visual name using the `getVisuals()` API.

   ```
    try {
    // Retrieve the page collection.
    const pages = await report.getPages();

    // Retrieve the active page.
    let activePage = pages.filter(function (page) {
        return page.isActive;
    })[0];

        const visuals = await page.getVisuals();
   console.log(
    visuals.map(function (visual) {
        return {
            name: visual.name,
            type: visual.type,
            title: visual.title,
            layout: visual.layout
        };
    })); catch (errors) {
    console.log(errors); }
   ```
2. After you the get the Visual name, use the `exportData` API to export the data.

   ```
     // Retrieve the target visual.
    let visual = visuals.filter(function (visual) {
        return visual.name === "VisualName";
    })[0];

    const result = await visual.exportData(models.ExportDataType.Summarized);
    console.log(result.data); }
   ```

Reference:
https://learn.microsoft.com/javascript/api/overview/powerbi/export-data

Comment: I'm getting error that function is not found...
However I didn't invest that much time into finding out what was causing this error, as we found it just as easy to just change the layout/design of the visuals in the power bi report and add them to a hidden page and fetching them from that page when embedding the visuals.